# "То, что" or "то, чтобы"

Tags: глаголы, предлоги, чтобы

I know that many prepositions can be followed by **то, чтобы** if we want to relate the preposition to a new sentence, rather than just a noun.

- Вместо того, чтобы...
- Настаивать на том, чтобы...
- Отказаться от того, чтобы...
  etc.

However, these may be set expressions. Apparently the conjunction чтобы cannot be used with just every preposition.

Once I heard that `кроме того, чтобы` is incorrect, and must be replaced with **кроме как**.

Here's my attempt at numbering a few usages of **то, что** and **то, чтобы**.

> Надеяться на то, что...
>
> Вопреки тому, что...
> Удивиться тому, что...
>
> Жалеть о том, что...
>
> Надо, чтобы...

1. Maybe the correct conjunction must be memorized for each case?
2. Still left an example with **тем** (instrumental).

The verb **рисковать** takes the instrumental case, thus we say `рисковать жизнью`.

But what if I want to risk a more elaborate sentence? Like "He risks losing his reputation".

Even though I could simplify and just say `"Он рискует потерей своей репутации"`, if I wanted to connect **рискует** to another verb, could the sentence become `"Он рискует тем, чтобы потерять свою репутацию"`?

3. Finally, if I want to say "on the brink of..." something other than a noun.

"On the brink of death" would be `на грани смерти.` But "on the brink of losing his job" wouldn't be `"на грани того, чтобы быть уволенным"`?

Comment: Since **чтобы** includes the conditional mood particle **бы**, **чтобы** is used when what follows it hasn't happened yet, and it is seen as [un]desireble, [im]possible, proposed, suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2. With ***рискует*** the subordinate clause is appended with the conjunction ***что*** and assumes future tense ***рискует тем, что потеряет***, but another way of attaching a verb is to simply say ***рискует потерять***
3. This is correct but another, a more compact version, is again the simple ***на грани быть уволенным***, still this only seem to work for the verb ***быть*** and maybe also ***стать***.

Comment: На грани увольнения would be even more compact.

Comment: indeed, but the OP looks specifically for the way to attach a verb

Comment: The complete version **на грани _того, чтобы_ быть уволенным** sounds _perfect_ to me while the 'compact' one **does not**. It is OK to use 'noun+infinitive' expressions like _нежелание быть уволенным_ (мастер делать то-то, etc), but '_грань быть уволенным_' sounds strange. Looks like the noun in such a construction should point at the _person_ to be fired (нежелание is _someone's_ wishing not) while _на грани_ (рубеже, пороге) refers to the _possibility of the action_ instead (_грань, порог, рубеж уволь**нения**_ - those are proper 'compact' expressions).

Comment: ***он - на грани быть уволенным*** seems pretty palatable, i do agree that ***на грани увольнения*** is more idiomatic

Comment: Aside from nouns meaning personal abilities or qualities, the nouns paired with an infinitive usually somehow point at the cause of its action ("**обусловливающие действие** условия или обстоятельства"):
https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=1bsoCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=P1z-9PeqwQ&sig=ACfU3U2KK2qFZBHDsgBSZivfy5XezT_IEA&w=1280
(Грамматика русского языка в упражнениях и комментариях, О. Глазунова - 2017, c. 90)
But the expression **на грани** is not about a _condition causing some action_: **грань** is a static thing, just a border between parts of an imaginary space.